# Set to 0 x% of non zero values in numpy 2d array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I tried different ways but it seems impossible for me to do it efficiently without looping through.

Input is an array y and a percentage x.

e.g. input is

```
y=np.random.binomial(1,1,[10,10])
x=0.5
```

output

```
[[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more information: do you mean any random x%?

Comment: updated it. thanks for the feedback

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: like you mean expected output or expected stack overflow answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one based on `masking` -

```
def set_nonzeros_to_zeros(a, setz_ratio):
    nz_mask = a!=0
    nz_count = nz_mask.sum()
    z_set_count = int(np.round(setz_ratio*nz_count))

    idx = np.random.choice(nz_count,z_set_count,replace=False)
    mask0 = np.ones(nz_count,dtype=bool)
    mask0.flat[idx] = 0
    nz_mask[nz_mask] = mask0
    a[~nz_mask] = 0
    return a
```

We are skipping the generation all the indices with `np.argwhere/np.nonzero` in favor of a masking based one to focus on performance.

Sample run -

```
In [154]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,3,(5000,5000))

# number of non-0s before using solution
In [155]: (a!=0).sum()
Out[155]: 16670017

In [156]: a_out = set_nonzeros_to_zeros(a, setz_ratio=0.2) #set 20% of non-0s to 0s

# number of non-0s after using solution
In [157]: (a_out!=0).sum()
Out[157]: 13336014

# Verify
In [158]: 16670017 - 0.2*16670017
Out[158]: 13336013.6
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few vectorized methods that might help you, depending on what you want to do:

```
# Flatten the 2D array and get the indices of the non-zero elements
c = y.flatten()
d = c.nonzero()[0]
# Shuffle the indices and set the first 100x % to zero
np.random.shuffle(d)
x = 0.5
c[d[:int(x*len(d))]] = 0
# reshape to the original 2D shape
y = c.reshape(y.shape)
```

No doubt there are some efficiency improvements to be made here.